Postgres Query - For discarding a particular data field from record for comparing 2 json data columns in 2 tables
Table 1 Data Column stored in jsonb format
{
"ID": "KL02",
"DOB": null,
"NAME": null,
"TITLE": null,
"LAND_AREA": 100,
"COUNTRY": "Amsterdam",
"SURNAME": null,
"FORENAME": null
                   }

Table 2 Data Column stored in jsonb format
{
"ID": "KL02",
"DOB": null,
"NAME": null,
"LAND_AREA": 100,
"COUNTRY": "Amsterdam",
"SURNAME": null,
"FORENAME": null
}
Table 1 data has TITLE in the JSONB whereas table 2 data doesn't have that field, For comparison of the data I will need to ignore the TITLE data and compare using query. Is there a way to write the query other than splitting the JSONB data into different columns and then comparing. I feel that comparison is tedious specially when we have more data in a record other than the above.
Tried using the split for data into different columns which I'm not so big fan of

There is always a cost to be paid. Either you pay it up front by creating a standard representation of the data or you pay it on each query by rearranging. At this point you have two different records saying the same thing in a different manner and you are trying to coerce them to be actually the same. I would say your time would be better spent creating a normalized view of your data and not have to resort to query hacks to get the same output.

What is your expected result?

You just have to check if column in table 2 is fully contained in column in table 1, like select t1.data_column @> t2.data_column  from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id =t2.id;  -> t

From the above table representation, the data in the column is in jsonb format, now the challenge with me is that the legacy system has one field / data / variable i.e TITLE, which the new system doesn't have, I have to ignore the TITLE in the legacy data and match it against the new system and ensure that the legacy and new system gives the same data using postgres query. Hope I have made it clear, please do ask if it needs more clarity

Thank you for your question! If I understand this correctly, you want to compare two JSON values, but ignoring a field?
This can be achieved quite easily:
with
t1(data) as (values ('{
        "ID": "KL02",
        "DOB": null,
        "NAME": null,
        "TITLE": null,
        "LAND_AREA": 100,
        "COUNTRY": "Amsterdam",
        "SURNAME": null,
        "FORENAME": null
      }'::json)
),
t2(data) as (values ('{
        "ID": "KL02",
        "DOB": null,
        "NAME": null,
        "LAND_AREA": 100,
        "COUNTRY": "Amsterdam",
        "SURNAME": null,
        "FORENAME": null
      }'::json)
)
select (t1.data::jsonb - 'TITLE') = (t2.data::jsonb - 'TITLE'),
        t1.data::jsonb            =  t2.data::jsonb
from   t1, t2;

The - (minus) operator takes a jsonb on the left, and a field name on the right. It is available for jsonb, not for json, so your json fields may require casting to jsonb (... ::jsonb). Also, the = operator is not available for json, but for jsonb.
Postgres type jsonb is a tokenized (normalized) form of json (e.g. insignificant white space is gone).

correction.. its jsonb and not json...

That is fine, then you can write just t1.data - 'TITLE' and so on, the cast (::jsonb) is not needed.

yes tried that.. from the query above, I could understand that we are doing a - from both tables the legacy and the new system, but its that the TITLE is there only in the legacy, so if we do a select (t1.data::jsonb - 'TITLE') = (t2.data::jsonb - 'TITLE') I see that there will be error instead I tried this select (t1.data - 'TITLE') = (t2.data). But the desired output that I was looking for was in some numbers but this is showing only boolean, is there a way to get the number / count instead of boolean

Basically,  after removing that particular data (TITLE) from legacy both the tables will look similar and now I want a comparison of the records between both tables and see the matched and unmatched record count

The absence of key "TITLE" in t2.data does not cause an error in t2.data - 'TITLE'. It is not clear to me what kind of counts you want, e.g. the count of elements in t1 which were matched, or the count for of each individual t1. Either will need a join, which depends on the table structure, which you should provide. Maybe that would also be quite a different question?

just observed that the '-' isn't working, it still shows the data with TITLE. May be something to do with the version I'm on?

Please send more of what is 'not working'. Also send you postgres version. I am currently using postgresql 15.
Also, your last edit of the question damaged some of the text, can you please check it?

may be that I'm using the pgadmin tool instead of postgres, causing this, I should have made a note initially itself. Apologies
What is not working
The '-Title' still gets retrieved from within the Jsonb data. The query works but gives the field that was removed.

@Harry Note that JSON is case sensitive, and the - goes outside of the quotes: - 'TITLE', not '-Title' or - 'Title'. Can you post the code you execute, what you expect, and what you get?
